# Change the gridview default 1900-01-01 to null or ""

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview, null

I am using this query to insert a null value to a datetime field:

```
echCommand="INSERT INTO GPEC_TBL_ECHEANCE(echeance, echeance_debut, echeance_fin, objectif_id) 
VALUES (null, " + System.DBNull.Value + "," + System.DBNull.Value + "," + newObjectifId + ")";

var echCommand = new SqlCommand(insertEchQuery, con);
```

But when displaying the GridView I'm still getting the date `1900-01-01` !

What should I add or modify to have a blank field instead of this ugly date in my Gridview  ?

Comment: Just a side note - do not use non-parameterised queries, if not absolutely neccessary!

Comment: Thankx, I've used `echCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@retrievedDebutEcheance", System.DBNull.Value);` in my original code but still had the same result :(

Comment: Your problem is probably not in that query.
Look into your database: is it really null, or does the db set a default value?
Look into the result set: is it null, or is it the default value?
And look into the NullValue, NullFormat or whatever it is called of the grid view.

Answer (score 0):

it is properbly the wrong place you are looking, when showing it in gridview, check if it returns a dbnull value